# Retrieving value from <select> with multiple option in React

Tags: javascript, dom, reactjs

The React way to set which option is selected for a select box, is to set a special `value` prop on the `<select>` itself, corresponding to the `value` attribute on the `<option>` element you desire to be selected. For a `multiple` select this prop can accept an array instead.

Now because this is a special attribute, I'm wondering what the canonical way is to *retrieve* the selected options in the same array-of-option-values-structure when the user changes things (so I can pass it through a callback to a parent component etc), since presumably the same `value` property won't be available on the DOM element.

To use an example, with a text field you would do something like this (JSX):

```
var TextComponent = React.createClass({
  handleChange: function(e) {
    var newText = e.target.value;
    this.props.someCallbackFromParent(newText);
  },
  render: function() {
    return <input type="text" value={this.props.someText} onChange={this.handleChange} />;
  }
});
```

What is the equivalent to replace `???` for this multiple select component?

```
var MultiSelectComponent = React.createClass({
  handleChange: function(e) {
    var newArrayOfSelectedOptionValues = ???;
    this.props.someCallbackFromParent(newArrayOfSelectedOptionValues);
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <select multiple={true} value={this.props.arrayOfOptionValues} onChange={this.handleChange}>
        <option value={1}>First option</option>
        <option value={2}>Second option</option>
        <option value={3}>Third option</option>
      </select>
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 80, accepted):

With `Array.from()` and `e.target.selectedOptions` you can perform a controlled select-multiple:

```
handleChange = (e) => {
  let value = Array.from(e.target.selectedOptions, option => option.value);
  this.setState({values: value});
}
```

target.selectedOptions return a HTMLCollection

https://codepen.io/papawa/pen/XExeZY

Comment: Any ideas on how to combine the selected options from multiple `select`s into one array? Say after grabbing them all via `document.querySelectorAll('select')`?

Comment: Note that at the time this question was asked, `selectedOptions` didn't have good compatibility, and is still not supported by IE. This would be the modern way to do it though.

Answer (score 126):

The same way you do anywhere else, since you're working with the real DOM node as the target of the change event:

```
handleChange: function(e) {
  var options = e.target.options;
  var value = [];
  for (var i = 0, l = options.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (options[i].selected) {
      value.push(options[i].value);
    }
  }
  this.props.someCallback(value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought there might be a shortcut rather than having to iterate manually. The closest thing I found was the `selectedOptions` property, but it doesn't work on a lot of older browsers.

Comment: typo on 6th line, should be `value.push(options[i].value)`

Comment: CoffeeScript version: `(option.value for option in e.target.options when option.selected)`

Comment: ES6 version: [...event.target.options].filter(o => o.selected).map(o => o.value)

Comment: lodash version: \_.pluck(_.filter(e.target.options, 'selected'), 'value')

Comment: underscorejs version: _.map(_.filter(e.target.options, function(item){ return item.selected }), function(item){return item.value})

Comment: destructure the params to make that es6 version even nicer...
`handleChange: ({ target: { options }}) => [...options].filter`

Comment: You can also destructure the ES6 arrows: `[...e.target.options].filter(({selected}) => selected).map(({value}) => value)`

Comment: This information should be part of React documentation.

Comment: TypeScript version: Array.from(e.target.options).filter(o => o.selected).map(o => o.value)

Comment: RE: ES6 version, while that _looks_ right it doesn't work. `event.target.options` is an `HTMLOptionsCollection`, not an Array.

Comment: You can use event.target.selectedOptions. It will provide directly selected options.

Comment: @TrueWill I'm sure you figured it out by now, but fyi for anyone else the spread operator can actually be applied to any iterable object. So it should work fine in this case.

Comment: @zrisher Negative, Ghost Rider.  `HTMLOptionsCollection` is not iterable.  However, `Array.from` still works with it:

`Array.from(event.target.options).filter(o => o.selected).map(o => o.value)`

Comment: I think rather running *filter and map* it is good to run only one iteration.

Comment: @UmairAhmed It would never, ever be an issue (performance-wise) for any `<select>`. If iterating "2N" is causing performance issues, then you shouldn't be using a `<select>` in the first place to hold all of those values. While it's important to think about performance, style is readability and I'll take the `.filter().map()` any day over a standard `for` loop. Just my two cents!

Comment: Changed line 9 to setState and It's working like a pro, thank you.

Answer (score 18):

Easiest way...

```
handleChange(evt) {
  this.setState({multiValue: [...evt.target.selectedOptions].map(o => o.value)}); 
}
```

Comment: This is nice, but `HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLOptionElement>` is not an array... Apparently `Array.from` works though. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49684109/29182

Comment: selectedOptions is no longer a property of target in Chrome Version 99.0.4844.51 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 13):

You can actually find the `selectedOptions` inside the target... no need to iterate over all the options. Let's imagine you want to send the values to an `onChange` function passed to your component as props: you can use the following function on the `onChange` of your multiple select.

```
onSelectChange = (e) => {
    const values = [...e.target.selectedOptions].map(opt => opt.value);
    this.props.onChange(values);
  };
```

Comment: At the time this question was asked, `selectedOptions` didn't have good compatibility. It's still not supported by Internet Explorer, so not really usable if you want IE support (at least without a polyfill).

Comment: selectedOptions Property is not available in Chrome Version 99.0.4844.51 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 12):

In case you want to use `ref` you can get selected values like this:

```
var select = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.selectRef); 
var values = [].filter.call(select.options, function (o) {
      return o.selected;
    }).map(function (o) {
      return o.value;
    });
```

2018 **ES6** update

```
  let select = this.refs.selectRef;
  let values = [].filter.call(select.options, o => o.selected).map(o => o.value);
```

Comment: will use this to substitute for my answer as well, since `selectedOptions` is not supported in IE

Comment: Here's a much cleaner, es6 way to do it :) 
[].filter.call(this.refs.selectRef.options, o => o.selected).map(o => o.value);

Answer (score 9):

In the case you would like to keep track of the selected options while the form is being completed:

```
handleChange(e) {
    // assuming you initialized the default state to hold selected values
    this.setState({
        selected:[].slice.call(e.target.selectedOptions).map(o => {
            return o.value;
        });
    });
}
```

`selectedOptions` is an array-like collection/list of elements related to the DOM. You get access to it in the event target object when selecting option values. `Array.prototype.slice`and `call` allows us to create a copy of it for the new state. You could also access the values this way using a ref (in case you aren't capturing the event), which was another answer for the question.

Comment: As mentioned in one of my other comments, browser support for `selectedOptions` seems pretty sketchy. But it would probably be the ideal solution if the support was there.

Comment: Ah true, it seems like IE still does not support this

Answer (score 4):

The following worked for me

```
var selectBoxObj = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.selectBox)
var values = $(selectBoxObj).val()
```

Comment: Correct, I used JQuery to retrieve the multiple values.

Comment: You don't need react dom or jQuery. Just retrieve the value from the onChange event

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it:

```
handleChange({ target }) {
    this.props.someCallback(
       Array.prototype.slice.call(target.selectedOptions).map(o => o.value)
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After spending a lot of time with this topic, and seeing that we are now all using mostly hooks and newbies may have never even dealt with classes in reactjs. I decided to update this answer so that people can easily deal with  using vanilla javascript and ES6. I am also including a link to [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-bartik-l0r7s6?file=/src/App.js) so that people can play with the code and modify it to their application.

Here is the code, it has excessive console logs so that people can figure out what is doing what in the code and how it is doing it.

```
import "./styles.css"
import {useRef} from 'react'


export default function App() {

  const handleSubmit = async(e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    let selected = [...recipeRef.current.options]
                .filter(option => option.selected)
                .map(option => option.value)
    console.log(new Date(), ' recipeType: ', selected)
    console.log(new Date(), 'with ref: ', [...recipeRef.current.options]);
    [...recipeRef.current.options].map(option => console.log(option,'; ',option.selected))
    console.log([...recipeRef.current.options].filter(option => option.selected))
    console.log([...recipeRef.current.options].filter(option=>option.selected).map(option => option.value))
  }
  const recipeRef = useRef()

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox example for select Multiple by Julio Spinelli</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div className="mb-6">
              <label htmlFor="text" className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300">Name of the Recipe</label>
              <input type="text" id="text" className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500" required ></input>
          </div>
          <div className="mb-6">
              <label htmlFor="recipeType" className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300">Recipe Type</label>
              {/* <input type="text" id="text" className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500" required onChange={(e)=>{setRecipeType(e.target.value)}} value={recipeType}></input> */}
              <select name="recipeType" id="recipeType" ref={recipeRef} multiple={true} size={3}> {/* Step 2 - Add the reference to `select` element */}
                <option value="unselected">unselected</option>
                <option value="Grill">Grill</option>
                <option value="Steak">Steak</option>
                <option value="Pizza">Pizza</option>
              </select>
          </div>
          <div className="flex items-start mb-6">
              <div className="flex items-center h-5">
              <input id="remember" aria-describedby="remember" type="checkbox" className="w-4 h-4 bg-gray-50 rounded border border-gray-300 focus:ring-3 focus:ring-blue-300 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:focus:ring-blue-600 dark:ring-offset-gray-800" ></input>
              </div>
              <div className="ml-3 text-sm">
              <label htmlFor="remember" className="font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300">Recipe uploaded?</label>
              </div>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" className="text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm w-full sm:w-auto px-5 py-2.5 text-center dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800">Save</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using event object:

```js
handleChange(e) {
    let selectedOptions = e.target.selectedOptions

    // selectedOptions looks like this:
    // {
    //      '0': <1st selected HTMLOptionElement>,
    //      '1': <2nd selected HTMLOptionElement>,
    //      '2': <3rd selected HTMLOptionElement>
    // }

    let newArrayOfSelectedOptionValues = Object.values(selectedOptions).map(
        opt => opt.value
    )

    this.props.someCallbackFromParent(newArrayOfSelectedOptionValues);
}
```

So the full `???` looks like this:

```js
Object.values(e.target.selectedOptions).map( opt => opt.value )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
dropdownChanged = (event) => {
    let obj = JSON.parse(event.target.value);
    this.setState(
        {
            key: obj.key,
            selectedName: obj.name,
            type: obj.type
        });
}


<select onChange={this.dropdownChanged} >
<option value={JSON.stringify({ name: 'name', key: 'key', type: "ALL" })} >All Projetcs and Spaces</option></select>
```

Comment: Add some more explanation to your solutions.

Answer (score 1):

```
onChange={(e) => setSelectedTaxes(e.map((tax) => tax.value))}
```