# react-select multiple option

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I'm trying to set `react-select` component for simple `select` with `multiple` options but i can't get it working even though it's everything set as docs say. When `multi` is `false`, `Select` works as intended with one `value` at a time, but when i set `multi={true}` it shows `value` as `undefined`.

When i give in `handleChange()` `event.target.value` it gives `undefined` aswell so thats why i've just used `event.value` to grab obj property. I'm still newbie to React so any tips about `state` would be appreciated if i'm doing something wrong here -_-

```
class StatisticsFilter extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState(event.value);
  }

const options =
[
  {
    value: 'foo', label: 'Foo'
  },
  {
    value: 'bar', label: 'Bar'
  },
  {
    value: 'baz', label: 'Baz'
  }
];

  render() {
    return (
          <Select
              value={this.state.value}
              name="filter__statistics"
              options={options}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              multi={true}
          />
    );
  }
}
```

Using `react-select v. 1.0.0rc`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving value from <select> with multiple option in React](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28624763/retrieving-value-from-select-with-multiple-option-in-react)

Comment: As a side note, according to [this page](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#overview), the event object has no `value` property.

Comment: @GJK well yeh, it should be `event.target.value` but then i'm receiving undefined values

Comment: My mistake. I see you're using a third-party library, not the native `select` tag. Disregard my comments.

Comment: Use event.value, not event.target.value.

Comment: Check it out https://www.npmjs.com/package/multiselect-react-dropdown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a few problems with your code. Firstly, the onChange callback will be passed in the value directly instead of the event. Secondly, an object has to be passed to `setState`.

Could you try changing your `handleChange` method to the following instead?

```
handleChange(value) {
  this.setState({ value });
}
```

You can also follow the example code for the Multiselect usage [here](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/master/docs/examples/MultiSelectSort.js).

Comment: Indeed, all i had to do was to change `even` parameter into `value` -_- should go sleep prooly

Answer (score 2):

In the following example, you have to check for old state and update to new values, but we can't change in state directly, so we have to use new value to use it in

> setState()

https://codepen.io/KhogaEslam/pen/PayjXW

```js
class FlavorForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { value: [''] }

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    let newVal = event.target.value
    let stateVal = this.state.value

    console.log(stateVal)
    console.log(newVal)

    stateVal.indexOf(newVal) === -1
      ? stateVal.push(newVal)
      : stateVal.length === 1
        ? (stateVal = [])
        : stateVal.splice(stateVal.indexOf(newVal), 1)

    this.setState({ value: stateVal })
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('Your favorite flavor is: ' + this.state.value)
    event.preventDefault()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Pick your favorite La Croix flavor:
          <select
            multiple={true}
            value={this.state.value}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          >
            <option value="" />
            <option value="grapefruit">Grapefruit</option>
            <option value="lime">Lime</option>
            <option value="coconut">Coconut</option>
            <option value="mango">Mango</option>
          </select>
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
      </form>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <FlavorForm />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```