# How to pass an array in query parameter reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, multi-select

I Am using multiselect dropdown, what i want is whatever i've selected in dropdown to send it to the server by calling an api which contains query param to accomodate these dropdown result.
I have made an array of selected items.
**Array(3) [ "IphoneXR", "Nokia", "Samsung" ]**
I want this array to get pass to below url like this: ****http://localhost:8080/details?dropdown=IphoneXR,Nokia,Samsung****.
With my approach i am ending up with this: **http://localhost:8080/details?dropdown[]=IphoneXR&dropdown[]=Nokia**. I am not sure why dropdown[] is coming twice. Can anyone please help me with it

Comment: Hello! Please share the code snippet that is causing issue for the community to be able to contribute.

Comment: This will be helpful to you
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763508/passing-arrays-as-url-parameter]

Comment: thanks @JayParmar, link is very useful.it worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the array into string and pass the value in query param.

```
multiSelectHandler = (option) => {
    const details = option.selectedItems;
   const stringData =  details.map(({value}) => `${value}`).join(',');
   console.log(stringData);
  };
```

Array: Details: Output in console

```
0: Object { value: "Iphone", label: "Iphone" }
    ​1: Object { value: "Samsung", label: "Samsung"}
```

After converting into string:Output in console, `Iphone,Samsung`

Now pass this stringData in queryparam

Answer (score 1):

If you are passing it directly to a url via the form actions it will sent it in the url as this: index.html?**cars**=saab&**cars**=opel&**cars**=audi

Try handling the form via js like this [How handle multiple select form in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50090335/how-handle-multiple-select-form-in-reactjs)