# How do I make react handler working for multiple values?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a handler which doesn't quite work as I wanted... I need to be able to change the 'quantity' value of many items. Right now, with my handler, if i try with multiple items, they will get updated with the last value entered. So there must be a way for me to enter multiple values and update items differently.. here is what I did so far:

```js
this.state.purchase.selected.map(item => {
                                    return (
                                        <Grid item xs={4}>
                                            <OrderItemsCard
                                                item={item}
                                                onChange={this.handleSelectedItemChange}
                                            />
                                        </Grid>
                                    )
                                })
```

```html
      
        this.handleSelectedItemChange = this.handleSelectedItemChange.bind(this) 
 
 handleSelectedItemChange(event) {
        let query = Object.assign({}, this.state.purchase);
        query.selected.map(item => {
            item.quantity = event.target.value
        })
        this.setState({purchase: query})
    }
```

Comment: Simular question has been answered here before. Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28624763/retrieving-value-from-select-with-multiple-option-in-react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a way to share your `onChange` function with multiple components, devising a way to distinguish the caller.

You can simply pass your `item` through to the `onChange` and use its values to determine the caller and perform whatever actions you wish.

This can be done as follows,

```
this.state.purchase.selected.map(item => {
  return ( 
    <Grid item xs={4}>
      <OrderItemsCard 
        item={item}
        onChange={(event) => this.handleSelectedItemChange(item, event)}
      />
    </Grid>
  );
})

handleSelectedItemChange(item, event) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: The answer I was looking for. btw, is there a way to prevent the values from changing in real time ? cuz i am also displaying the initial ones

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "changing in real time".

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for `throttling` or `debouncing`. Give this article a read-through and see if it helps: https://codeburst.io/throttling-and-debouncing-in-javascript-b01cad5c8edf