# React multi select not able to select negative value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multi-select

Hi i am using react multi select with negative and positive values.When i select -1 
it is automatically changed to 1. So not able to select -1. other values working fine.

```
 class FlavorForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: '1'};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('Your favorite flavor is: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Pick your favorite flavor:
          <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} multiple>
            <option value="-1">Grapefruit</option>
            <option value="0">Lime</option>
            <option value="1">Coconut</option>
            <option value="2">Mango</option>
          </select>
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <FlavorForm />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Please help how to select -1 with react multi select.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1zwhabms/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the values property in state as an array, i.e.:

```
this.state = { 
  values: []
}
```

And then, change handleChange to this:

```
handleChange(event) {
    let choices = event.target.selectedOptions;
    let final = [];
    for(let i=0; i<choices.length; i++) {
      final.push(choices[i].value);
    }
    this.setState({ value: final });
  }
```

And it should work.

Here is a link to a working version:
https://codesandbox.io/s/p3705q0zm

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Use array for value if multiple is true based on the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#the-select-tag).
For multiselect behavior use options as described [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33184997/5506730).

```js
class FlavorForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ['1']};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange = ({target}) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      value: [].filter.call(target.options, o => o.selected).map(o => o.value)
    }));
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('Your favorite flavor is: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Pick your favorite flavor:
          <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} multiple>
            <option value="-1">Grapefruit</option>
            <option value="0">Lime</option>
            <option value="1">Coconut</option>
            <option value="2">Mango</option>
          </select>
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <FlavorForm />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: But I need multiselect only.Anyhow thanks for your effort!

Comment: I upgraded with multiselect behaviort.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that my console was logging the following error

> Warning: The `value` prop supplied to  must be an array if `multiple` is true.

I took the liberty of fixing that and coincidentally the `-1` selection started working:

```
class FlavorForm extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { values: [] }

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
  }

  handleChange (event) {
    const values = this.state.values.includes(event.target.value)
      ? this.state.values
      : this.state.values.concat(event.target.value)
    this.setState({ values: values })
  }

  handleSubmit (event) {
    alert(`Your favorite flavor is: ${this.state.values}`)
    event.preventDefault()
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Pick your favorite flavor:
          <select
            value={this.state.values}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            multiple
          >
            <option value="-1">Grapefruit</option>
            <option value="0">Lime</option>
            <option value="1">Coconut</option>
            <option value="2">Mango</option>
          </select>
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove value attribute from select element it is invalid there.

```
<select onChange={this.handleChange} multiple>...</select>
```

Comment: According to this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21733847/react-jsx-selecting-selected-on-selected-select-option
and this
https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#the-select-tag
using `value` attribute on the `<select>` element _is_ the preferred way.