# Single onChange that can handle single- and multi-select Form changes

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I have a `Form` with a couple `Form.Select` attributes.  My `onChange()` works for the `<Form.Select>` attributes without `multiple` set.  However, it cannot handle selections from `<Form.Select>` attributes that do have `multiple` set.

I would like to have a single onChange function that can handle data changing for instances of `Form.Select` with or without the "multiple" flag set.

**The Form Class:**

```
class SomeForm extends React.Component {
    handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.props.onSubmit(this.state);
    };


    onChange = event => {
        const {
            target: { name, value }
        } = event;

        this.setState({
            [name]: value
        });

        console.log("name: " + name)
        console.log("value: " + value)
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} onChange={this.onChange}>

                <Form.Select label="Size" options={sizes} placeholder="size" name="size" />

                <Form.Select
                    label="Bit Flags"
                    placeholder="Bit flags"
                    name="flags"
                    fluid
                    multiple
                    search
                    selection
                    options={bits}
                />

                <Form.Button type="submit">Submit</Form.Button>
            </Form>
        );
    }
}
```

The logs are never called when I select options from the `Form` with `multiple` set.

Some possible bits to populate the `options` prop of `Form.Select`:

```
const bits = [
    {key: '1', text: "some text 1", value: "some_text_1"},
    {key: '2', text:  "some text 2", value:  "some_text_2"},
];
```

**How can I modify onChange() to handle both `Form.Select` attributes as listed above?**

Please note that this question is different from question on StackOverflow which are concerned only with an `onChange` that can only be used for updating an array.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple selects are a weird beast. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28624763/retrieving-value-from-select-with-multiple-option-in-react) describes how to retrieve the selected values.

If you want to define a form-level handler, you need to make an exception for multiple selects:

```js
    const onChange = (event) => {
        const value = isMultipleSelect(event.target)
          ? getSelectedValuesFromMultipleSelect(event.target)
          : event.target.value
        this.setState({[event.target.name]: value})
    };

    const isMultipleSelect = (selectTag) => selectTag.tagName === 'SELECT' && selectTag.multiple

    const getSelectedValuesFromMultipleSelect = (selectTag) => [...selectTag.options].filter(o => o.selected).map(o => o.value)
```