# not work `onChange` and not work `setState` in `select` tag. (multiple) in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a `select` tag containing the `optgroup` and `option` tags which is multiple.

When I select the items, the `state` is not updated and the `onChange` does not work.

I want the value of the `option` tag to be transferred to `state` when the item or items are selected !!!.

```
const FunctionalComponent = () => {

const [mystate , setMyState] = useState([]);


return(

<div>

     <select
         onChange={(e) => setMyState(e.target.value) }
         className='form-control'
         multiple='multiple'
         value={mystate}
         >
          
          {datas.map((obj) => (
            return (
                 <optgroup key={obj.title} label={obj.title}>
                    {obj.map((o) => (
                        <option key={o.id} value={o.id}>{o.name}</option>
                    ))}
                 </optgroup>
                    );
            ))}
     </select>

</div>


)


}

export default FunctionalComponent
```

Thanks to those who help me.

Comment: Could you include the `dates` list too?

Comment: I get the data, but the onChange does not work. My data only contains the title, id, name!@mahan

Comment: It should be `datas.map` not `data.Map`. You're also trying to `map` over `obj` which doesn't make sense unless it's an array are you're calling it `obj` for some reason. Adding a sample of your data would help us debug the problem. I'm suspicious of `obj => obj => (` too.

Comment: That setMyState default value is an empty list, but event.target.value is a string.

Comment: As you know, several options can be selected!Can you send me a valid code that works?@mahan

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how `datas` is structured it's difficult to write code for it, but based on how I *think* it's structured here some working code.

1. Intialiase state as an array.
2. Have your handler [get the `selectedOptions`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49684109/1377002), and get each option's value. Add that array to your state.
3. Here `datas` is an array objects. Each one has a `title`, and another array of objects containing the option data. `map` over the main array, and then `map` over the options array.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Example({ datas }) {

  const [mystate , setMyState] = useState([]);

  function handleChange(e) {
    const options = e.target.selectedOptions;
    const values = Array.from(options, option => option.value);
    setMyState(values);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <select
        onChange={handleChange}
        className="form-control"
        multiple="multiple"
        value={mystate}
      >{datas.map(obj => {
         return (
           <optgroup
             key={obj.title}
             label={obj.title}
           >{obj.options.map(obj => {
             return (
               <option
                 key={obj.id}
                 value={obj.id}
               >{obj.name}
               </option>
             );
           })}
           </optgroup>
         );
       })}
     </select>
    </div>

  );

}

const datas = [
  {
    title: 1,
    options: [
      { id: 1.1, name: 1.1 },
      { id: 1.2, name: 1.2 },
    ]
  },
  {
    title: 2,
    options: [
      { id: 2.1, name: 2.1 },
      { id: 2.2, name: 2.2 },
    ]
  },
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example datas={datas} />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
form-control { width: 200px; height: 200px}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: That makes no sense in terms of the code in your question. You're trying to access the title property of an object (`obj.title`). You didn't add a sample of your input data to your question even after being asked twice so I had to make something up based on your code. @fqsof

Comment: I can't help you any more. Sorry.