# How to get an array of currently selected items of a multiple-selection HTML select?

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

**How to get an array like `["Apple", "Orange"]` of currently selected items of a multiple-selection HTML `select`?**

We could probably parse the `<option>` HTML of `s.selectedOptions` but there is surely a more standard way:

```js
var s = document.getElementById('mySelect');
document.onclick = () => {
    console.log(s.selectedIndex);
    console.log(s.selectedOptions);
};
```

```html
<select multiple id="mySelect">
  <option>Apple</option>
  <option>Orange</option>
  <option>Pineapple</option>
  <option>Banana</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get all selected values of a multiple select box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866169/how-to-get-all-selected-values-of-a-multiple-select-box)

Comment: @stdob-- Most answers of this linked question are outdated, the accepted answer here is far better for nowadays (2022) IMHO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently there is no better way but to `map` over the `selectedOptions`.

```js
document.getElementById('mySelect').addEventListener('change', function(e){
  console.clear();
  const selectedVals = [...this.selectedOptions].map(o => o.value);
  console.log(selectedVals);
});
```

```html
<select multiple id="mySelect">
  <option>Apple</option>
  <option>Orange</option>
  <option>Pineapple</option>
  <option>Banana</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks @Unmitigated. What does the `[...this.selectedOptions]` syntax do? I don't remember.

Comment: @Basj It converts the `selectedOptions` into an array (using spread syntax).

Comment: Thanks for the name which I didn't know, here I found it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Answer (score 0):

Checking the value of each option element(option.selected) can be a method, but using the selectedOptions method of the select element is also a standard method.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedOptions
`An option is considered selected if it has an HTMLOptionElement.selected attribute.`

Additionally, if you want a simpler code, please refer to the link below. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49684109/11618421